# Using the multirow package with tex4ht to generate tables in HTML document

Tags: tex4ht, multirow

I am trying to generate a HTML document using $\LaTeX$ and I am experiencing some minor bug with tex4ht and the *multirow* package (I am working with MikTex 2.9 and WinEdt 7).

It appears that the "multirowed" items are not vertically centered on the HTML output while this is the case when using PDFLatex.

Here is a simple example illustrating the issue (taken from the *multirow* package documentation):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{4}*{Common g text} & Column g2a \\
& Column g2b \\
& Column g2c \\
& Column g2d \\
\hline
\multirow{3}*{Common g text} & Column g2a\\
\cline{2-2}
& Column g2b \\
\cline{2-2}
& Column g2c \\
\hline
\multirow{4}*{Common g text} & Column g2a\\\cline{2-2}
& Column g2b \\\cline{2-2}
& Column g2c \\\cline{2-2}
& Column g2d \\
\hline
\multirow{4}*{\minitab[c]{Common \\ g text}} & Column g2a\\
& Column g2b \\
& Column g2c \\
& Column g2d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF looks good:
[pdf table](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83085593/pdfOutputTable.png)

but not the HTML version:
[html table](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83085593/htmlOutputTable.PNG)

Has anybody experienced such issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs additional details and the links of the desired output are by now broken